# Custom Screener using pine script In Trading View

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript code and I want to run that code on all US stocks universe like a scanner is that possible in Trading View.

Thanks and Regards,
Dishant

Comment: This is currently not possible in Pine.

Comment: The closest thing you can do is to write a strategy and set an alert for that strategy on each of the symbols. you can set 400 concurrent alerts in the premium plan.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. However i almost complete create a software for custom screener :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).